# Load a js file in the head?

Tags: theming, javascript

My theme is set up so that if I add javascript files through the info file they are loaded at the bottom of the page. This is generally what I want however I want to load a few specific javascript files in the head. Is there a 'standard' way of doing this? I would like to use the normal minification and aggregation if possible.